# vb.net add row in row xml

Tags: xml, vb.net

I wont add row in row, I have xml data base for my software but I don't understand how add row for this style.

```
<facture>
  <commande>000156</commande> 
    <date>Jan 1, 2003 14:30:00</date>
    <commis>adsd</commis>
    <client>0</client>
    <item_liste> 
        <item_id>0</item_id>  
        <item_quantité>4</item_quantité>
        <item_codebarre>0</item_codebarre>
        <item_name>hejwkhe</item_name>
        <item_price>55</item_price>                
        <item_tax>no</item_tax>
     </item_liste>
    <item_liste> 
        <item_id>2</item_id>  
        <item_quantité>5</item_quantité>
        <item_codebarre>0</item_codebarre>
        <item_name>ghskjfdghsfd</item_name>
        <item_price>24</item_price>                
        <item_tax>yes</item_tax>
     </item_liste>
     <montant> 270 </montant>
 </facture>
```

I now add normal row

```
dataTable1.Rows.Add(img12, "", "", "", "", "", "")
```

Thanks for help and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Show result what you expected

Comment: The result is what I show up, but if I have 5 item in my bill I have 5 <item_liste> in <facture>, and <facture> is't only row I have <client> , <inventaire> , <facture> , <settings> , <userlog> and my xml base is   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soft>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<facture>" +
                    "<commande>000156</commande>" +
                    "<date>Jan 1, 2003 14:30:00</date>" +
                    "<commis>adsd</commis>" +
                    "<client>0</client>" +
                    "<item_liste>" +
                        "<item_id>0</item_id>" +
                        "<item_quantité>4</item_quantité>" +
                        "<item_codebarre>0</item_codebarre>" +
                        "<item_name>hejwkhe</item_name>" +
                        "<item_price>55</item_price>" +
                        "<item_tax>no</item_tax>" +
                        "</item_liste>" +
                    "<item_liste>" +
                        "<item_id>2</item_id>" +
                        "<item_quantité>5</item_quantité>" +
                        "<item_codebarre>0</item_codebarre>" +
                        "<item_name>ghskjfdghsfd</item_name>" +
                        "<item_price>24</item_price>" +
                        "<item_tax>yes</item_tax>" +
                        "</item_liste>" +
                        "<montant> 270 </montant>" +
                    "</facture>";


            XElement facture = XElement.Parse(xml);
            List<XElement> item_liste = facture.Descendants("item_liste").ToList();
            XElement newItem_liste = new XElement("item_liste", new XElement[] {
                new XElement("item_id", 3),
                new XElement("item_quantité", 5),
                new XElement("item_codebarre", 0),
                new XElement("item_name", "xyz"),
                new XElement("item_price", 30),
                new XElement("item_tax", "no")
            });
            item_liste.Last().ReplaceWith(new object[] { item_liste.Last(), newItem_liste });
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dr As DataRow

 ' loop around the XML Nodes 
  For Each node As XmlNode In XML

   ' declare a new row in your datatable 
 dr = dataTable1.NewRow()
'get what ever values you want off of the attribute of the node ie item name
 dr("item_name") = node.Attributes("item_name").Value
 dr("item_id") = node.Attributes("item_id").Value

 ' add the row to your data table
 datatable1.rows.Add(dr)
```

Comment: Hi, I don't undertand, how add new value if I add same value? Thanks.